# Apple Sign In : Validating identityToken at server side

Tags: ios, xcode, oauth, jwt, apple-sign-in

Is it now mandatory from apple to implement the "sign in with apple" if you offer to your customer alternative like "facebook sign in". That completely crazy because if you **can't** implement the "sign in with apple" then you need to remove from your app the alternative "sign in with facebook" and then for your old users who already registered with facebook, they will simply ... **lose their access** to their account!

This was just to introduce my problem, I'm trying to get Sign In with Apple integrated into a native iOS app, and am running into troubles trying to validate the data coming back in `ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential` over the REST API on my app's server-side.

Apple stops short of how to use everything they give us above (`ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential`) to verify sign ins on your server. After all, while operating on-device we can trust Apple's APIs not to lie to us, but as soon as we send this data to the server we need a way for said server to verify that someone isn't spoofing a user string. Normally you use the users' password for verification that they can access a given account, but we don't have that anymore.

**I m under delphi,** and **their is no viable solution to work with JWT** (there is few but they all look like more experimental, not widely used and tested, and their code is huge), so I need an endpoint server to validate the IdentityToken (for example google offer https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=xxx). I can't find anything and I m a little shocked that apple force you to use their sign in process but don't offer you any tool to validate the token of the server side.

How can I validate in my server the IdentityToken without any jwt tools ?

Comment: I don't really see how it is Apple's problem if your server platform doesn't have libraries to work with JWT. It is a very common open standard used by lots of  authentication providers, not just Apple. A JWT is just a base64 encoded JSON document; surely your server can handle base64 and JSON? Once you have the JSON you need to [check a few things](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user) The only thing that may be a little tricky is verifying the signature, but again, presumably your server has a crypto library that can help.

Comment: Once you have validated the identity token you need to exchange the authorisation code for a refresh token by calling the apple token endpoint.

Comment: @Paulw11 no i don't have crypto in my server :( and it's not easy, I m quite sure many developers will simply not verify the identityToken :( apple is really bad on this side!